# Associated Name spiderweb

Tags: mysql, database-design

Say for instance I have the following entries in my table:

```
ID - 1
Name - Daryl
  
ID - 2 
Name - Terry

ID - 3
Name - Dave

ID - 4
Name - Mitch
```

I eventually wish to search my table(s) for one specific name, but show all associated names. For instance,

> Searching Daryl will return Terry, Dave & Daryl.
>
> Searching Terry will return Dave, Daryl & Terry
>
> Searching Mitch will only return Mitch.

The current table housing the names is as followed:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `members`
--

CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `ID` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `GuildID` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `ToonName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `AddedOn` date NOT NULL,
  `AddedByID` int(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `members`
--

INSERT INTO `members` (`ID`, `GuildID`, `ToonName`, `AddedOn`, `AddedByID`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Daryl', '2020-01-17', 5),
(2, 1, 'Terry', '2020-01-17', 5),
(3, 1, 'Mitch', '2020-01-17', 5),
(4, 1, 'Dave', '2020-01-17', 5);

--
```

For Reference. GuildID will be a default search criteria based on the searchers login details. With a spiderweb like this, how would I go about creating another table (or another Column) to bring a combined search spiderweb structure based on the search criteria?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE `Associated`(
    `ID` INT(255) NOT NULL,
    `MainID` INT(255) NOT NULL,
    `SecondaryID` INT(255) NOT NULL,

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Associated` (`ID`, `MainID`, `SecondaryID`) VALUES

(1, 1, 2) -- Daryl Associated With Terry
(2, 1, 4) -- Daryl Associated With Dave
```

But I feel this will make an over complicated value structure with alot of redundant inputs. Is there a more effective way to create a unified search?

The whole idea of operation is that each name is Individual. So certain Entries can be put under Daryl, Terry acting alone. But one search will bring together all associated Names by searching one name then pull together total entries based on the alisas?

Comment: This is extremely unclear. That includes "spiderweb".  Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.  When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Re "The whole idea" & "along the lines of":  A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" etc that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly". PS Ask exactly 1 clear specific non-duplicate question.

Comment: What is a "spiderweb"? Do you mean a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics))?

Comment: @DarylGill if I search for 'DA' than 2 rows will return with their similar results right ?? what is the number of rows in member table?  it will help us to find a optimize solution. What is the login of similar results (spiderweb). Or is it decided by some team ?

Comment: One more thing is how many maximum similar results you need to get with your query ?

Comment: For this scenario more preferable is  Directed graph.Because Associated table have more search based node and depends on other table node so directed graph divides its column in nodes.

Comment: @Daryl Gill, Want to know if my answer helped you!

Answer (score 9):

You can try This

```
Select IFNULL(m.ToonName , members.ToonName) as ToonName 
from members 
LEFT JOIN Associated on Associated.MainID = members.ID 
LEFT JOIN members as m on m.ID = Associated.SecondaryID 
Where members.ToonName = "Mitch"
```

While you have entry for 
"**Mitch**" in Associated table it will return you **Daryl** and when you dont have associated Id it will return the name from members table.

And If you will check this with **"Daryl"**, it will give you Two results,

```
Select IFNULL(m.ToonName , members.ToonName) as ToonName 
from members 
LEFT JOIN Associated on Associated.MainID = members.ID 
LEFT JOIN members as m on m.ID = Associated.SecondaryID 
Where members.ToonName = "Daryl"
```

In case you want all the names in a single column you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` as @flash suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can directly get the data from the following SQL statement.

---

For Individual row

```
SELECT `members`.ToonName FROM `associated` JOIN `members` ON associated.SecondaryID = members.ID WHERE `associated`.MainID = (SELECT ID FROM `members` WHERE ToonName = 'Daryl');

# Output: **ToonName**
Terry,Dave
```

---

Grouping Row

```
// You can also group all rows by comma from following statement
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`members`.ToonName) FROM `associated` JOIN `members` ON associated.SecondaryID = members.ID WHERE `associated`.MainID = (SELECT ID FROM `members` WHERE ToonName = 'Daryl');

# Output: **ToonName**
    Terry
    Dave
```

Comment: Also, note that you are making mistake while inserting members records. Use **ToonName** instead of **Name** in insert query. As you have declared ToonName in the database schema.

Comment: The other question to ask would be how would inputting this data go? Each user can have in excess of 25 associated. When Inputting the associated into the table. Would that have to be 3 separate queries grouping then have to concat all results of the individual searches?

Comment: INSERT INTO `associated` (`ID`, `MainID`, `SecondaryID`) VALUES (3, 3, 1);
// With this statement I have entered the record of **Mitch** with **Daryl**

Comment: Also, in case of confusion you can share more data with approx 100 records, so we can check for the desired output, or we misunderstand something

Answer (score 3):

**Plan A**

Add a column to each `member`.  It is the number (or name) if the one group he/she belongs to.  Terry, Dave & Daryl would get one value; Mitch would get a different value.  Index the column for efficient lookup of related names.

**Plan B**

Implement a graph, like you suggested.  Some tips:  Get rid of `id`; instead have `PRIMARY KEY(MainID, SecondaryID)`.  The is an issue to resolve...  This design implies a "directedness" of the relationships:  Terry --> Dave, but not necessarily Dave --> Terry.  If you want to force it to be reflexive, the force two rows to be inserted or insert the two IDs in an canonical order, but then check both directions.

Also, you need to "walk the graph".  This is best done with a Recursive CTE.  For that feature, you need MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2.

**Plan C**

Without the directedness of B, you run into more difficult issues.  One is "cluster analysis".  Another is messy paths and loops in the 'graph'.  Let's avoid these.

Comment: It _sounds_ like your problem is a graph - modeling these in SQL is hard. Google is your friend - this is a good intro: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/handling-graphs-sql/

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Modeling a graph relationally is not hard, it is trivial. edge(n,m)

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** Yes you need a second table `Associated` and it will not make completed structure.

Below is the query to get the required result

```
SELECT ID, ToonName,

(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ToonName) FROM Associated
    JOIN members child ON SecondaryID = child.ID
    WHERE MainID = parent.ID
)

FROM members parent
```

You can also use join but I think, in this case sub query will be better.

**NOTE :** your tables need some optimization like remove `ID` field from `Associated` table, Add index etc.